# Access to elements from the DOM

Tags: javascript

I create elements dynamically using jquery. this is my code

```
function showArticles(res) {
    var output = '';
    res.articles.forEach(function (item) {
      output +=
        '<div class="col-12 col-lg-4 item-article" data-name="'+ item.author +'>'+
          '<p>' + item.description + '</p>'

          +
        '</div>'
      });
    articleWrapper.append(output);
```

I want to get access to the `data-name` attribute

```
var itemArticle = $('.item-article').attr("data-type");
console.log(itemArticle)
```

Return `undefined`.

How to get access to the `data-name` attribute why is this happening?

Comment: change `$('.item-article').attr("data-type");` to `$('.item-article').attr("data-name");`

Comment: `data-**type**` must be `data-**name**`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `var itemArticle = $('.item-article').data("name");`

Answer (score 1):

You get the wrong attribute.

After `showArticles` is called, you can do this:

```
var itemArticle = $('.item-article').attr("data-name");
// Or
var itemArticle = $('.item-article').data("name");
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you tried to use is jQuery code. You will need to import the jQuery lib if you want to use that. Because this question is not tagged with jQuery i assume you want to us e plain javascript.

You can do this with the function `querySelectorAll()` to get the matched elements. Loop over those elements and run the `getAttribute()` function to get the attribute value.

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.item-article');

items.forEach((item) => {
  var dataName = item.getAttribute('data-name');
});
```